# Jquery jqte and document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqte

I've tried many different places for the script with `$('#editable').jqte();` inside.
Sometimes the editor shows up, sometime it does not, it seems non-deterministic.

It's like my document is not ready when I call the `jqte()` function.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Parcours, technique, sujets, peinture figurative, couleurs, émotion." />

    <title>Creating Page</title>

    <link href="/bundles/usersite/css/homepage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/bundles/usersite/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="/bundles/usersite/css/jquery-te.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script>
      $(document).ready
      (
        function()
        {
          $('#editable').jqte();
        }
      );
    </script>
    </head>

  <body class="oneColFixCtrHdr">
  <div id="container">
    <div id="mainContent">
      <div id="editable">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**
Due to my twig template the below is missing in some cases (like the above one):

```
 <script src="{{ asset('bundles/usersite/js/jquery-te.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

works better with javascript linked !!!!!!

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsbin.com/IrIXowI/1) ([source](http://jsbin.com/IrIXowI/1/edit))

Comment: LOOOL. Sorry guys, the problem was due to my twig templates.

    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/usersite/js/jquery-te.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>

was missing in the above, but not missing every times...

thanks !